# Creating a batch version of a script that renames Vertex Groups

Tags: scripting, vertex-groups

I have the following code, which creates a button in the panel which when clicked creates a vertex group from all vertices in a selected obj. Is there a way I can edit to so that when I click the button it cycles through every obj in the scene and repeats the script? Essentially creating a vertex group for each object with that object's name.

```
import bpy


def main(context):
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_add()
    bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_assign()

#obj = bpy.context.active_object
    sel_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects
    for obj in sel_obj:
        for g in obj.vertex_groups:
            print(g.name)
            g.name = obj.name


class CreateVertexGroup(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "myops.create_vertex_group"
    bl_label = "Create Vertex Group"

@classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

def execute(self, context):
    main(context)
    return {'FINISHED'}

class CustomVertexGroupScriptsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Custom Vertex Group Scripts Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_createvertexgroup"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "data"

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    obj = context.object

    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)

    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("myops.create_vertex_group")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CreateVertexGroup)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomVertexGroupScriptsPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CreateVertexGroup)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomVertexGroupScriptsPanel)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.myops.create_vertex_group()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your indent is off. Please also add what you have tried.

Comment: I've fixed the indent, as of now not tried anything as unsure what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Indent doesn't look fixed to me.  Paste code from your editor, select it in bse editor and hit the code {} button or ctrl - K.

Answer (score 1):

**Using API methods**

In `main` in the following, saves the current mode, sets mode  to `'OBJECT'`, iterates through all mesh objects in `context.selected_objects` either uses existing vertex grouped named after object, or creates a new one and assigns all vertices to it with a weight of 1. Then returns `context.object` back to its original mode.

```
import bpy
def main(context):
    mode = context.object.mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    meshobs = [o for o in context.selected_objects
            if o.type == 'MESH']
    for mo in meshobs:
        me = mo.data
        vg = (mo.vertex_groups.get(mo.name)
                or mo.vertex_groups.new(mo.name))
        # add all verts
        vg.add(range(len(me.vertices)), 1, 'REPLACE')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=mode)


main(bpy.context)
```